# Attempt to assign property "nombre" on null

Tags: laravel

En un proyecto laravel utilizo una vista para actualizar un registro, cambiándole el campo "nombre".
Esta es la función del controller que realiza dicha tarea:

```
public function insert_name(Request $request){    
    $registro = Produccion::find($request->id);    
    $registro->nombre = $request->nombre;    
    $registro->save();    
    return redirect("/secado");    
}
```

Y este código funciona cuando el formulario es este:

```
<form action="{{url('insert_name')}}" class="displayCenter">
    <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$registro->id}}">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Sin embargo cuando utilizo este, no funciona:

```
    <form action="{{url('insert_name')}}" class="displayCenter">
        <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
        <input type="search" id="buscador" autocomplete="off">  
        <div class="overflowShort displayCenter">
            @foreach($registrosPersonal as $registro) //Genera dinámicamente inputs de tipo radio según otra base de datos
            <div class="option" data-value="{{$registro->nombre_completo}}">
                <input type="radio" name="nombre" value="{{$registro->nombre_completo}}">
                <label>{{$registro->nombre_completo}}</label>
            </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$registro->id}}">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
```

Este segundo en vez de introducir el campo "nombre" en un input text lo hace por medio de inputs tipo radio que son generados dinámicamente en base a otra base de datos. Funciona correctamente en aquellos formularios para crear registros, pero al momento de actualizar este salta el siguiente error:

> Attempt to assign property "nombre" on null

Comment: Imagino que te da ese error en la línea `$registro->nombre = $request->nombre;`. Te está diciendo que `$registro` vale `null`. Podría ser debido a que la instrucción anterior, `$registro = Produccion::find($request->id);`, falló (o cualquier motivo por el que devuelva `null` esa llamada). Puedes mandar para depurar el valor de dicha variable y, además, deberías incluir un control para reaccionar en ese caso.

Comment: Ha funcionado, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como ya te mencionan en el primer comentario bajo la pregunta, el error se dá en la línea:

```
$registro->nombre = $request->nombre;
```

Y se debe a que `$registro` vale `null`.

Y esto, a su vez, se debe a que la instrucción anterior:

```
$registro = Produccion::find($request->id);
```

Ha asignado `null` a esa variable, ya que el método `find()` devuelve `null` cuando no existe un registro que tenga la llave primaria proporcionada, en este caso `$request->id`.

Ahora bien...  ¿Por qué está pasando esto?

Pues en la vista estás obteniendo la propiedad `id` de la variable `$registro`, que asumo tiene como valor la instancia de un modelo Eloquent:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$registro->id}}">
```

Pero ese input está después de este foreach:

```
@foreach($registrosPersonal as $registro)
    //...
@endforeach
```

Y como se vé, la variable a la que se asigna el valor de cada elemento del array o colección sobre la que itera, también se llama `$registro`. Esto hace que se pise el valor de `$registr`o antes de que intentes obtener la propiedad `id` de tu modelo.

Se me ocurren dos formas de resolverlo:

Poner el input que tomará el valor de la id del modelo antes del foreach:

```
<form action="{{url('insert_name')}}">
    //...
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$registro->id}}">

    @foreach($registrosPersonal as $registro)
        //...
    @endforeach
    //...
</form>
```

O lo que considero mas "limpio", no pisar el valor de `$registro` con la variable del foreach. Por ejemplo, en vez de:

```
@foreach($registrosPersonal as $registro)
```

usa

```
@foreach($registrosPersonal as $valor)
```